# Conversion Linq result to object type in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq

I need vb.net syntax of below answer(given in c#)-

[How can I convert Linq results to DTO class object without iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124931/how-can-i-convert-linq-results-to-dto-class-object-without-iteration)

I have tried converting to vb.net at [this link](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/), but it does give compilation errors.

Following is the output from above convertor -

```
Public Function [Get]() As List(Of User)
Using db = New MyContext()
    Return (From u In db.UsersOrder By u.FirstNameNew User() With { _
        Key .Id = u.pkUser, _
        Key .Username = u.Username, _
        Key .Password = u.Password, _
        Key .Active = u.Active _
    }).ToList()
End Using
End Function
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the code you tried and also your compilation errors?

Comment: It's working fine now. I am posing my latest syntax

Answer (score 1):

Well, the Linq query is obviously messed up. And since there's no `User` class in the code you tried to convert, the converter tried to use the `Key` keyword, which is only used for anonymous types.

So the correct code should look like:

```
Public Function [Get]() As List(Of User)
    Using db = New MyContext()
        Return (From u In db.Users
                Order By u.FirstName
                Select New User() With { 
                    .Id = u.pkUser, 
                    .Username = u.Username, 
                    .Password = u.Password, 
                    .Active = u.Active 
                }).ToList()
    End Using
End Function
```

assuming the following `User` class:

```
Public Class User
    Public Id As Integer
    Public Username As String
    Public Password As String
    Public Active As Boolean
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked now - 
Following are the keyword were missing in convertor.

1. Order
2. Select New
3. removed keyword Key

and final code is as below -

```
Public Function [Get]() As List(Of User)
Using db = New MyContext()
Return (From u In db.UsersOrder Order By u.FirstNameNew select new User() With { _
    .Id = u.pkUser, _
    .Username = u.Username, _
    .Password = u.Password, _
    .Active = u.Active _
}).ToList()
End Using
```