# Entity Framework Navigation Properties are not listed while creating a converter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have following working Entity Frameowrk code for creating DTO from entity framework result. It created InvoiceDTO object that has a `List<ServiceChargeDTO>` property  inside it. This is done referring to [Mapping Linq Query results to a DTO class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333005/mapping-linq-query-results-to-a-dto-class)

```
public class InvoiceDTO
{
    public int InvoiceID { get; set; }
    public List<ServiceChargeDTO> ServiceChargeLineItems { get; set; }
    public decimal InvoiceTotal { get; set; }
} 

public InvoiceDTO GetInvoiceByID(int invoiceIDParam)
{
    InvoiceDTO invoice=null;
    using (var db = new PortalEntities())
    {
        var invoices = from a in db.Invoices
                       where a.InvoiceID == invoiceIDParam
                       select new InvoiceDTO
                       {
                           InvoiceID = a.InvoiceID,
                           InvoiceTotal = a.InvoiceAmount,
                           ServiceChargeLineItems =
                                (from b in db.InvoiceServiceXrefs 
                                where a.InvoiceID == b.InvoiceID 
                                select new ServiceChargeDTO
                                {
                                    ServiceChargeID = b.ServiceChargeID,
                                    Quantity = b.ServiceCharge.Qty,
                                    UnitPrice=b.ServiceCharge.UnitPrice,
                                    Amount=b.ServiceCharge.Amount
                                }
                                ).ToList()
                       };

        invoice = invoices.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    return invoice;
}
```

Here data from related tables is successfully retrieved.

```
InvoiceServiceXrefs.ServiceCharge.Qty
```

I need to change this approach and make it **convert** method.

```
public InvoiceDTO GetInvoiceByID(int invoiceIDParam)
{
    var invoice2 = null;
    using (var db = new PortalEntities())
    {
        var invoices2 = from b in db.Invoices
                        where b.InvoiceID == invoiceIDParam
                        select b;
        invoice2 = ToInvoiceDTO(invoices2.FirstOrDefault());
     }

    return invoice2;
}
```

But the navigation properties are not getting listed when I type `invoice.InvoiceServiceXrefs.`.

[image]

How to get the navigation properties correctly and create `InvoiceDTO` object with `List<ServiceChargeDTO>`?

Comment: `invoice.InvoiceServiceXrefs` is a collection. Similar to the first code snippet (`from b in db.InvoiceServiceXrefs`), you have to iterate over it to use the entities it contains. Note however that this `ToInvoiceDTO` approach is less efficient: it will trigger multiple queries.

Comment: the `invoice` argument is of type `Invoice`, not `InvoiceDTO` and you do not show any code for a class called `Invoice`

Comment: @Lijo Have any of the answers helped to answer your question? Can you update please.

Comment: Frankly, I don't understand the bounty. If you still had questions after my comment above you could have simply asked. Now I don't know what's left unclear to you.

Comment: You need to interate through your InvoiceServiceXrefs. Bu before that you also need to eager load it before FirstOrDefault() call cause it wont bring you InvoiceServiceXrefs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pretty much the same code to map your ServiceChargeLineItems, that you used in your initial query

```
private static InvoiceDTO ToInvoiceDTO(Invoice invoice)
{
    InvoiceDTO e = new InvoiceDTO()
    {
        InvoiceID = invoice.InvoiceID,
        InvoiceTotal = invoice.TotalAmount
    };

    e.ServiceChargeLineItems = invoice.InvoiceServiceXrefs.
                               Select(b => new ServiceChargeDTO
                               {
                                   ServiceChargeID = b.ServiceChargeID,
                                   Quantity = b.ServiceCharge.Qty,
                                   UnitPrice = b.ServiceCharge.UnitPrice,
                                   Amount = b.ServiceCharge.Amount
                               }).ToList()

    return e;
}
```

UPDATE:

Following is how it is called. Note the use of ToList() on invoicesQuery. This approach issues multiple queries.

```
var invoicesQuery = from a in db.Invoices
             where a.InvoiceID == invoiceIDParam
            select a;

List<InvoiceDTO>  listTest = invoicesQuery.ToList().Select(x => ToInvoiceDTO(x)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you need to map your `List<InvoiceServiceXrefs>` to `List<ServiceChargeDTO>`.

```
private static InvoiceDTO ToInvoiceDTO(Invoice invoice)
{
    InvoiceDTO e = new InvoiceDTO()
    {
        InvoiceID = invoice.InvoiceID,
        InvoiceTotal = invoice.TotalAmount
    };

    foreach(var invRef in invoice.InvoiceServiceXrefs)
    {
        e.ServiceChargeLineItems.Add(new ServiceChargeDTO
        {
            ServiceChargeID = invRef.ServiceChargeID,
            Quantity = invRef.Qty,
            UnitPrice = invRef.UnitPrice,
            Amount = invRef.Amount
        });
    }

    return e;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

When you ran LINQ query on db.Invoices in your GetInvoiceByID method, it became an IQuerable variable invoices2. If you do not want to do perform nested LINQ query in one shot, better return them as DbSet invoices2 and use it to create your desired DTO like this

```
public DbSet"<"Invoices">" GetInvoiceByID(int invoiceIDParam)
{
     var invoice2 = null;
     using (var db = new PortalEntities())
     {
          var invoices2 = from b in db.Invoices
                          where b.InvoiceID == invoiceIDParam
                          select b;
          //REMOVE THIS invoice2 = ToInvoiceDTO(invoices2.FirstOrDefault());
      }

      return invoice2;
}
```